# Ruby on Rails: Using ransack to query between date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have been trying to use checkboxes to filter listings by date.
Each checkbox has a date, and I want it so when you click a checkbox, it shows the listings for that entire week.

```
#events_controller
  def index
    @q = Event.ransack(params[:q])
    @events = @q.result
    @weeks = Semester.current.range.select {|w| w.wday == Semester.current.start_dt.wday}.map(&:to_s)
```

-

```
#index.html.erb
  <div class="col-10">
    <div class="dates ">
      <%= search_form_for @q, id: "filters_click", remote: true do |f| %>
        <div id="dates">
          <% i = 1 %>
          <% @weeks.each do |date| %>
            <div class="ck-button ">
              <label class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center">
                <%= hidden_field_tag :start_dt_lteq, (date.to_date + 7.days) %>
                <%= radio_button_tag('q[start_dt_gteq[]', date, nil, class: "date" ) %>
                <span class="align-self-center">
                      Week <br />
                  <%= i %>
                  <% i += 1 %>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

-

```
#index.js.erb
$(".events").html('<%= j render @events %>');
```

-

```
#events.coffee
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('input:radio').change ->
    $("#filters_click").submit();
```

Currently, it will send the search params back to the server but the results don't appear in the view. Any thoughts?

Comment: i think if because u are using remote: true, you have to add local: true to make it behave like remote: false.